# HTML5 email validation avoiding js call

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<form>
<input type="email" id="login_email" required>
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" ng-click="signIn()">
</form>
```

The problem with above code is that signIn() method gets called even if there is an email validation error from HTML5 side. In general how to ensure that signIn() method gets called only when all the input validation of the form are successful?

Comment: Why wouldn't you instead attach a handler to the form's submit event?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$pristine` to find out if the form is empty, and `$invalid` to find out if the form is populated but has invalid values (maybe an incorrect email, for example).

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
    <button ng-click="signIn()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pristine">Save</button>
</form>
```

So now your submit button will be disabled (not clickable) until your form is valid.

**EDIT**

In order to validate only with HTML5 validation, add a `name` attribute to your form and you can access the validity of it during submission:

```
<form name="myForm">...</form>

$scope.signIn = function(){
    if ($scope.myForm.$valid){
        // do sign in logic here
    }
}
```

Maybe even inline the logic on your submit button (if it works):

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" ng-click="myForm.$valid && signIn()">
```

So `signIn` would only be called if the first part was true.

**EDIT 2**

Based on the information found on the [AngularJS docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), can you try the following as well?:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
    <button ng-click="signIn()" ng-disabled="signIn()">Save</button>
</form>

$scope.signIn = function () {
    if ($scope.myForm.email.$error.required) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

We are now following the `$scope.myForm.email.$error.required` syntax approach.

Try logging `$scope.myForm` or `$scope.myForm.email` and see what you get as you modify the value.

Comment: the above code disables my submit button until the user has filled out the form correctly, but the HTML5 validation errors are shown only on submitting the form. Disabling the submit button wont be the right thing to do here

Comment: Are you sure you want to use HTML5 validation only? Why not provide your custom error message and design? HTML5 validation will limit you later on when you want additional validations that are not currently built into it. Plus, you can't style them or edit the error message. But if that's what you want I can come up with a solution.

Comment: I dont really require any customized message or design , just need to ensure that my js is called only after HTML5 validation passes. Just trying to save effort and time by avoiding to reinvent the wheel here as my requirements are pretty limited here

Comment: Can you try to updated example or something similar?

Comment: No luck, the inline logic still calls the signIn method even if validation fails. 
The other method of using scope is also not working on debugging found that scope.myForm.$valid is always true , even when the HTML5 validation is failing. Do we need an ng-form or something similar to inject the form in "$scope"

Comment: disabling the submit button approach again?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it to disable. Meant to say try using that syntax in your submit function to check the validity of the form control. Updated answer.